# How can I redirect Slim/PHP

Tags: php, slim

I'm trying to redirect after go to the /add and do the function but when I click the button, the page go to url/add, realize the function and don't redirect, someone know how can I do it? All works except redirect.

```
<?php
    use \Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;
    use \Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;

    require '../vendor/autoload.php';

    $app = new \Slim\App();
    $app->get('/domain/{id}', function (Request $request, Response $response, array $args) {
        $id = $args['id'];
        $response->getBody()->write("Hello, $id");

        return $response;
    });
    $app->get('/domain', function () {
        $jsonContents = file_get_contents('data/data.json');
        echo $jsonContents;
    });
    $app->post('/add', function () {
        $jsonContents = file_get_contents('data/data.json');
        $name = $_POST['addname'];
        $url = $_POST['addurl'];
        $data = json_decode($jsonContents, true);
        $last_item = end($data);
        $last_item_id = $last_item['id'];
        $data[] = array(
            'name' => $name,
            'url' => $url,
            'id' => $last_item_id+1
        );
        $json = json_encode($data);
        file_put_contents('data/data.json', $json);
        header('location:../index.php');
    });
    $app->run();
```

Comment: try to not send a relative url in the location header (incl. the scheme - http(s), hostname and absolute path), e.g. `http://www.yoursite.com/index.php`), and use a capital 'L' for "Location".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved, I deleted `header('location:../index.php');` and I added `return $this->response->withRedirect('../index.html');`